# Random Images from Array - Android

Tags: java, android, arrays, image, arraylist

Hi I am getting the error "unexpected token" at for (int i=0; i<4; i++)

I have two arrays with the same images inside. In this example I have 2 arrays with 3 images (images are the same in each array). I want to get 2 random images from each array and they must be the same image (therefore being a pair). Any input on what im doing wrong would be great!

THEN I want to put these images onto image buttons.

```
public class Card {
ArrayList<Integer> list=new ArrayList<Integer>();
ArrayList<Integer> list1=new ArrayList<Integer>();
Random r1=new Random();
int[] imageArray1 = new int[] {R.drawable.raptors, R.drawable.okc_thunder, R.drawable.spurs};

int[] imageArray2 = new int[] {R.drawable.raptors, R.drawable.okc_thunder, R.drawable.spurs};
for(int i=0;i<4;i++)
{
    while(true)
    {
        int next=r1.nextInt(10)+1;
        if(!list.contains(next))
        {
            list.add(imageArray1[next]);
            list1.add(imageArray2[next]);
            break;
        }
    }
}
array1 = convertIntegers(list);
array2 = convertIntegers(list1);


public static int[] convertIntegers(List<Integer> integers)
{
    int[] ret = new int[integers.size()];
    Iterator<Integer> iterator = integers.iterator();
    for (int i = 0; i < ret.length; i++)
    {
        ret[i] = iterator.next().intValue();
    }
    return ret;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why use two arrays if they hold the same data anyway?

```
int[] imageArray1 = new int[] {R.drawable.raptors, R.drawable.okc_thunder, R.drawable.spurs};
int[] imageArray2 = new int[] {R.drawable.raptors, R.drawable.okc_thunder, R.drawable.spurs};
```

Just do:

```
int[] imageArray = new int[] {R.drawable.raptors, R.drawable.okc_thunder, R.drawable.spurs};
```

Also I don't get the point why you're using array lists and while loops.
I would do it like this:

```
public int getRandomCard() {
    return this.imageArray[r1.nextInt(3)];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I used two arrays because I needed a pair of pictures. So in this example I had 3 pictures (cards). But there would be 2 of each card (6 cards / 3 pairs). Out of the three pairs I need to randomly choose 2 pairs! Will the code you provided do the same?